# Service"jenkins"(Jenkins)failed to start,verify that you have sufficient provileges to start the system file

Tags: jenkins, installation, service

[If you are getting this error than follow the following steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs9UD.png)

When you install jenkin in C:\Program Files\Jenkins after that select the path for JRE

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221
and also remember the bit 64 and 32 beacuse if you select the path C:\Program Files (x86) than you fails to install the jenkins successfully

Comment: Is this an assertion, an observation or a question? Did you read the Jenkins Documentation or Stack Overflow [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) docs? What is the question and how is this impeding you?

Comment: I couldn't get my error to work with your suggestion. However, I've found a way to fix this problem. Please see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308841/jenkins-failed-to-start-verify-that-you-have-sufficient-privileges-to-start-sy