# Failed to start Jenkins - Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services

Tags: jenkins, installation, service, windows-installer, uninstallation

I installed Jenkins previously but it had some issue (there was no start icon) in the folder, so I uninstalled it. Now I'm trying to install it again, but it tends to pop this error:

[image]

I tried all the solutions mentioned in this post , but no success - [Jenkins failed to start - Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308841/jenkins-failed-to-start-verify-that-you-have-sufficient-privileges-to-start-sy)

As mentioned in the option 2 of the post, I tried to start jenkins in services but got a 1067 error

[image]

I read a lot of similar posts, but none of them really helped. I believe my user has enough privileges to work without causing any trouble, so the underlying problem is something else. Please help me figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
Turns out Jenkins doesn't work on other JDKs except for 8,11. And I have the 14th version. I'm putting the link to the answer that helped me change the JDK version.

[Jenkins requires Java versions [8, 11] but you are running with Java 16 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69066139/jenkins-requires-java-versions-8-11-but-you-are-running-with-java-16-from-c)